# First activity comes to foreground somehow

Tags: android

I have my launcher activity A which from there starts activity B (based on fb login). I finish activity A before starting B. I also tried using flags such as

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

However sometimes while working with activity B, all of the sudden Activity A pops up. I have no idea where to debug or where to see why A is being brought to the front all of the sudden? Any hints how this can be traced?

I wouldve shared code but sharing thousands of lines wouldn't make sense :)

EDIT:

I tried to simplify the question. Here is more details, in reality There are 3 activities.
A->B->C

A is the launcher activity which takes you to activity B after you choose LOGIN.
B you put the info, then takes you to C. C is where  I want to stay on. Somehow, Activity A comes up after some time. If I hit the back button, it takes me back to activity C ( which what I want)

Activity A to B  code:

```
intent = new Intent(LoginRegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B to C code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Add the important code parts, like where you call `startActivity()` and the code around that.

Comment: from your explanation i think android kill your application in background and if you come again launcher activity is called . please provide more info so we can help you.does this happen when you open your activity from background to foreground ???

Comment: can you share your code A to B Activity ?

Comment: Write `finish()` after you write `startActivity()` in your activity A class.

Comment: Here is more details in the question. I tried the finish method and the flags method

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` apparently the flag is ignored for API lower than 11.You can use `IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and import import `android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat;` from support library for work on API 10.

Comment: I am targeting ICS and above :)